# Using $state.go() with parameters gives error when content is passed from database in string format

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create an event log for the user so he can see what happens.
but i have some trouble with passing the url as string to $state.go

The function looks like this:

```
    $scope.viewEventBigList = function(url) {

        $state.go(url);

    };
```

But if i do some tests

```
       $scope.viewEventBigList = function(url) {

        var workingUrl= "app.additem";

        $state.go(workingUrl);

        var doesNotWorkWithParams = "app.showestimatedetail,{ 'param3' : '1' }";
        var doesNotWorkWithParams2 = "'app.showestimatedetail',{ 'param3' : '1' }";
        var doesNotWorkWithParams3 = "app.showestimatedetail,{ param3 : 1 }";

        $state.go(doesNotWorkWithParams);

        //But this does work 
        $state.go('app.showestimatedetail', { 'param3':'1'});


    };
```

First i thought i had some issues with bad syntax in my string. So the compiler did not get it. But as you can see i already tried it in 3 different ways but i keep getting `Could not resolve 'app.showestimatedetail,{ param3 : 1 }' from state 'app.dashboard'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function accepts 3 params go(to, params, options) (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

When you do `var doesNotWorkWithParams = "app.showestimatedetail,{ 'param3' : '1' }";` and pass doesNotWorkWithParams as the only argument, you are only passing one long string as the 'to' param and that exact route does not exist.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
$scope.viewEventBigList = function(url, params) {

    $state.go(url, params);

};
```

and then call this function in code as:

```
$scope.viewEventBigList("app.showestimatedetail", { param3 : 1 });
```

or if you must pass a single string like you are now, you can try something like:

```
 $scope.viewEventBigList = function(url) {

    var splitLoc = string.indexOf(',');

    $state.go(
         url.substring(0, splitLoc), 
         JSON.parse(url.substring(splitLoc+1)));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

ui.router takes as a first param state name or:

```
$state.go('contact.detail') will go to the 'contact.detail' state
$state.go('^') will go to a parent state.
$state.go('^.sibling') will go to a sibling state.
$state.go('.child') will go to a child state.
$state.go('.child.grandchild') will go to a grandchild state.
```

as a second param you can pass object with additional parameters where key is a parameter name registered in router

So none of these 3:

```
var doesNotWorkWithParams = "app.showestimatedetail,{ 'param3' : '1' }";
var doesNotWorkWithParams2 = "'app.showestimatedetail',{ 'param3' : '1' }";
var doesNotWorkWithParams3 = "app.showestimatedetail,{ param3 : 1 }";
```

is a proper formed state name.
Only the last one is OK.

```
$state.go('app.showestimatedetail', { 'param3':'1'})
```

First argument is a state name and second one is an object.

For more info visit [Documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Answer (score 0):

Your url string does not work because the method `go` from `$state` does not parse parameters inside a string where the state is located.

maybe you were trying to do something like this

```
"app.showestimatedetail({'param3' : '1'})"
//this just works with ui-sref in HTML
```

if you wish to pass an state with its parameters inside a string in JavaScript side, you could do this

lets pretend we have a state string like this

```
    //this is a simple approach
    var url = "app.showestimatedetail@{ 'param3' : '1' }"; 
    //We use @ as separator of the state with the parameters

    //Now we store the state string and parameters in different variables
    var state = url.split("@")[0],
        params = JSON.parse(url.split("@")´[1]);

    //We now have the params and state name in different places, so we
    //can continue with going to the desired state with our parameters

    $state.go(state, params);
```

of course this example depends on your string to have `@` as separator between the state name and the parameters